# Android app signing for android devices that don't support Google Play

Tags: android

So I am trying to develop an application that will be used on android devices, the problem is that these devices don't use Google Play. So if I would sign my app, can I still use Google Play to manage it or do I need to manage them myself? If I need to manage them myself what do I need to do then?

Thanks in advance,

Billy Cottrell

Comment: I don't actually know the answer to this, but it seems nonsensical that you would be able to use Google Play to manage an app that's not on Google Play.

Comment: @HenryTwist yes that's true, I just thought that it wouldn't be necessary to Install Google Play to actually check if the key is correct or not, perhaps by using API's or so, I mean not that I know, but it was a possibility so.

Comment: Well surely you can just sign your app as normal? The Google signing process is just an extra step ontop of the standard key signing.

Comment: @HenryTwist Yeah, I signed my key without an issue, its just that I don't know whether it was necessary or not since I want to be able to auto update the app as well, I am kind of new to that part of signing and publishing an app and especially maintaining it.

Comment: There's lots of information here about updating without the Play Store: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251575/how-to-autoupdate-android-app-without-playstore-like-facebook-app-or-any-contes