# Is there a way to update applications without google play store then remotely via a web server

Tags: java, android

I created an application through android studio but I want it to update without google play store.  Of course my app is not on the google play store.  I've also read other questions always here but they are from 2 years ago that's why I proposed a question recently

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to autoupdate android app without playstore? Like Facebook app or any Contest app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251575/how-to-autoupdate-android-app-without-playstore-like-facebook-app-or-any-contes) specify, do you want to use an alternative store, or update automatically from the app itself

Comment: yes the article is for me, scrolling down the article I noticed a section of the libraries. I clicked the first appupdater, however I would like to be followed step by step if possible

Comment: as I read here: https://github.com/javiersantos/AppUpdater

Comment: if you see i should have a web server for the apk ? to use this github ?

Comment: The AppUpdater library seems like hasn't been updated in some years, tho, same as the other libraries in the list. You may want to consider what features your app needs (a banner or dialog alerting the user of new update? does the app need to find updates in the background? etc), to find a better library or build it yourself

Comment: You could use your own server, but I think it would be easier to just upload it on Github. I would use three files: a file with the newest version, a file of the newest apk, and a text file containing the urls of the other two. Last one would be ideally in separated place than the other two, it would be useful in case you want to change the server url remotely. Is the app for a limited low number of users, or is it for a large one?

Comment: the app is for a limited number for users.  I kindly ask you to follow me step by step on github as you said.  Thank you

Comment: instead I'll answer the first question I would rather see a banner saying that the update must be done

Comment: Recommend me other libraries or if it's easy to create the library

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to update applications without using the Google Play Store by utilizing alternative methods such as updating remotely via a web server. One approach is to implement an Over-The-Air (OTA) update system. Here's a general outline of how it works:

**Web Server Setup**: Set up a web server to host the updated application files. This server will serve as the source for distributing the updated versions of the application.

**Application Version Tracking**: Implement a version tracking mechanism within the application. This can be done by storing the current version number locally or by making periodic requests to the server to check for updates.

**Update Check**: The application periodically contacts the web server to check for new versions. This can be triggered at regular intervals or when the user launches the app.

**Download and Install**: If a newer version is available, the application downloads the updated APK file from the web server. The file is then installed on the device using the appropriate installation mechanisms, such as the PackageInstaller API on Android.

**Security Considerations**: Ensure the update process includes proper security measures, such as verifying the integrity and authenticity of the downloaded files to prevent malicious updates.

It's worth noting that implementing an OTA update system requires careful planning and consideration of security, user experience, and compatibility. Additionally, distributing applications outside of official app stores may have certain limitations and requirements depending on the platform and device policies.

Therefore, it is important to thoroughly research and understand the platform-specific guidelines and best practices before implementing such an update system.

Comment: hello thank you for the answer being that I'm new would you like to answer me following step by step because I really don't know how to move

Comment: Because I'm new I don't even know what to use to create a web server so I need a step-by-step guide

Comment: as a web server is apache ok?  I don't know, tell me more in detail