# Update APK-file of my running Xamarin app on Android Q device

Tags: android, xamarin

I am developing an application, that downloads a newer APK file from server.
The download to storage works fine, now it should update without user interaction.

I have read all the documentation on Android, Xamarin and similar issues on StackOverflow. But i cannot get it work as expected. There is no installation intent and no exception from source code, the application just continue running. Please, do you know what i missed here?

MainActivity.cs

```
public bool Install(string filePath)
{
    Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
    if (!file.Exists())
    {
        return false;
    }

    // please allow permission for package install
    if (!global::Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.CanRequestPackageInstalls())
    {
        var intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetAction(global::Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageUnknownAppSources);
        intent.SetData(global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + global::Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }

    try
    {
        // Android 10.x and newer
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Q)
        {
            global::Android.Net.Uri uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(global::Android.App.Application.Context, global::Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName.ToString() + ".provider", file);
            InstallPackageAndroidQAndAbove(file.AbsolutePath, uri);
        }

        // omitted older Android versions, working
        else if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N) { }
        else { }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


public void InstallPackageAndroidQAndAbove(string filePath, global::Android.Net.Uri apkUri)
{
    var packageInstaller = global::Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.PackageInstaller;
    var sessionParams = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstallMode.FullInstall);
    sessionParams.SetAppPackageName(global::Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName);
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.S)
    {
        sessionParams.SetRequireUserAction( (int)global::Android.Content.PM.PackageInstallUserAction.NotRequired );
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Tiramisu)
    {
        sessionParams.SetPackageSource((int)global::Android.Content.PM.PackageSource.LocalFile);
    }

    int sessionId = packageInstaller.CreateSession(sessionParams);
    var session = packageInstaller.OpenSession(sessionId);

    AddApkToInstallSession(filePath, session);
          
    // Create an install status receiver.
    var intent = new Intent(this, this.Class);
    intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionInstallPackage);
    intent.SetData(apkUri);
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.NoHistory | ActivityFlags.ExcludeFromRecents | ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
    global::Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);

    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(global::Android.App.Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
    var observer = new PackageInstallObserver(packageInstaller);
    observer.InstallFailed += OnInstallFailed;
    packageInstaller.RegisterSessionCallback(observer);
    global::Android.App.Application.Context.SendBroadcast(intent);

    // Commit the session (this will start the installation workflow).
    // -> But nothing happens here, there is no intent on my device, 
    // -> observer does not handle InstallFailed, and no exception is thrown
    session.Commit(pendingIntent.IntentSender);      
}
        
                
private async static void AddApkToInstallSession(string filePath, PackageInstaller.Session session)
{
    using (var input = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var packageInSession = session.OpenWrite("com.Westfalia.Savanna.CrossClient", 0, -1))
        {
            await input.CopyToAsync(packageInSession);
            packageInSession.Close();
        }
        input.Close();
    }

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
}
        
private void OnInstallFailed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

with permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

- INSTALLPACKAGESINSTALLPACKAGES
- READEXTERNAL_STORAGE
- REQUESTDELETE_PACKAGES
- REQUESTINSTALL_PACKAGES
- RESTARTPACKAGES
- UPDATEPACKAGES_WITHOUT_USER_ACTION

I tested on real devices by Samsung and Honeywell with Android > 10.

I expected an install intent and restart of the running application.

Comment: We usually detect updates automatically after launching the app. Or manually check if there is a new version in the settings menu before deciding whether to update or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question suggests that you don't use the Playstore or something similar.

I would suggest to take a look here: [How to autoupdate android app without playstore? Like Facebook app or any Contest app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251575/how-to-autoupdate-android-app-without-playstore-like-facebook-app-or-any-contes)

Auto Updater would be the Library you need to Update an App while running.
https://github.com/NDMAC/android-auto-updater-client

Since Auto Update is an Java library you have to Bind it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/